# Does anyone have a network trace of a successful 'Block found'

Tags: litecoin, pushpool

I'm working on porting some front-end pool software to Postgres. I've got at test net set up and can mine directly to litecoind from cgminer. But I'm getting false positives reported to cgminer and other weirdness when I attempt to mine through pushpool. cgminer will go through three or four 'accepted' lines, then "block found", the shares get recorded in the database, but there's no 'upstream_result'. I've been running network traces, and cannot find anything that differentiates an accepted share to a 'found block'.

From the network traces, all the litecoind does is send new work to pushpool. I see no work from pushpool being submitted to litecoind.

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: One thing I missed in my test configuration was that I didn't have a "blocknotify" process in place. I've corrected that, but I'm still looking for a trace of 'block found' through pushpool.(06/06)